# When exactly PHP interpreter is launched?

Tags: php, cgi, interpreter, server

So, when exactly PHP interpreter is working?

As I understood, the flow is something like this:

Request -> CGI ( e.g php-fpm ) or server module ( e.g mod_apache ) -> server -> output

Is it run by interfaces/modules? If yes, does it mean that it is inside those interfaces/modules? Or somewhere else?